# Background not 100% of page

Tags: html, css

Wondering if anyone could help me resolve this problem, when I make the window smaller, I want it to scroll and not be responsive BUT I need the backgrounds to follow to the end. They just stop at window size.

I've tried:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But it did not work.
[Check it live here to see the problem in action.](http://flatfilthy.se/skolan/)

Comment: Please include the essential code for the question within the post. How and where are you actually applying the `background-image`? What other `background-*` styles are being set with it? Linking to a live demo is fine and often helpful, but the question should still hold its own after the contents of the link have changed.

Comment: try using min-width and min-height - you are setting the maximum width of the body and html tags to the viewport width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you have a container that is `1100px` and you are centering your image inside that container (with `margin: 120px auto 0 auto`) so it's doing what it should - the container hits the edge and image stays centered inside. If you want it to move all the way to the edge then you need to take it out of the container and just center it within the page.